# How to get object sub values in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular5, angular7

I am trying to get object sub values but not working.I do not know where I did mistake from my code.Anyone can find the solution?I am trying to show li values from object.

test.json:

```
"main":[{

"power":"coming",
"cell":"2min",
"li":[
 {
"text":"Lorem ipsom"
 },
 {
"text":"Ipsom klgtoy"
 },
 {
"text":"Klopi"
},
{
"text":"Mkhoi ipsom"
}
]
}];
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="val of main let i=index">

<ul>

<li>{{ val.li.text  }}</li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: change `"power":"coming:,` to `"power":"coming"`

Comment: @IanPreglo: Sorry..Edited but not working

Comment: you still have this `"power":"coming":,`... make sure that it is this `"power":"coming",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all i dont know what is tha test.json file 
you must write your js in .ts or .js file 
and the right way to declare array and object is :

```
 var main=[{
     power:"coming":,
     cell:"2min",
     li:[{
        text:"Lorem ipsom"
         },
         {
         text:"Ipsom klgtoy"
         },
         {
         text:"Klopi"
         },
         {
         text:"Mkhoi ipsom"
         }
      ]
}]
```

also you didn't close li arrays

and for getting each text you must go through 2 loops first getting each object of main array and second one getting each object of li array

```
<div>

<ul *ngFor="val of main let i=index">

<li *ngFor="eachText of val.li let i=index">{{ eachText  }}</li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Any other way is there?

Comment: other way to get the value ? unfortunalety no you can say ```<li *ngFor="eachText of main[0].li let i=index">{{ eachText  }}</li>  ```
and remove the first loop but it only gets first object of array and if you add another object to your main array it wont be shown

Comment: what about the array and the file ? ddi you fixed them as well 
if you upload your code on stackblitz or ... i can help you better

Comment: GettingError: Can not bind 'ngFor' since it is not a know property of 'li'

Comment: <li *ngFor="let eachText of val.li let i=index"> use this